# Having problems updating my flash player

Tags: flash

I have been trying to figure this one out with the questions already asked about flash player but were not able to do it. If I go to this site https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/ it will say that my Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202 is no up to date. So I pressed update now and got the .tar.gz file. Typed in about:plugins in firefox and got the path for my flashplayer to be /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so . Went in through the command line and first renamed to old libflashplayer.so to libflashplayer.so100 and then copied the new one in to the folder. Restarted firefox but it still says that I have an outdated version of flash. Am I even doing it right? Is there a apt-get command to get the latest update for flash player? Because my youtube and so on runs slow so I figured its because I dont have the latest update.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there nothing we as linux users can do? I would have thought that as some 40% of the worlds web sites are run with flash player code. This effectively means that if we use the internet, then we must use something like Windows and forget linux. There must be some alternative, for linux users, surely?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you! Just open up terminal and type this in.

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install upgrade flashplugin-installer
```

Hope this fixes it for you!

Comment: when I run the first command it says: flashplugin-installer is already the newest version. When I run the second command it says: E: Unable to locate package upgrade.

Comment: There should be two dashes before the word upgrade. But I suspect you would find that it is already up to date.

Answer (score 1):

It is telling you that because the most recent Flash is 11.9.900.117.  However, Flash decided to stop supporting Linux versions at 11.2.202.310.  The Linux version will receive security updates so it should be safe but will not receive new features.

The Mozilla website is only reading the fact that you have an old version installed, so it is telling you that is is vulnerable, it is not any more than any other Flash Player...

If you truly want to run the latest version on Linux (at least in the browser) then your only option is to use Chrome(not Chromium, it must be Google Chrome).  They have a Pepper-based Flash player that installs in Chrome only...

If you have any other questions, the site that I used for reference is [Flash Player Help / 
Find version](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html)